# Generating number dependent on 2 lists

Tags: c#

Here is some simple code to show my problem:

```
 void method()
 {
   for(int i = 0;i<=99)
   {
     method1();
     method2();
   }
  }

void method1()
{
    if(Randombool())
    {
        bool exists = true;
        int n;
        while(exists)
        {
            n=RandNum(100);
            exists = list1.Exists(num => num == n);
        }
        list1.add(n);
    }
}

void method2()
{
    int n;
    bool exists = true;
    bool exists2 = true;
    while(!(exists && !exists2))
    {
        n = RandNum(100);
        exists = list1.Exists(elem => elem == n);
        exists2 = list2.Exists(elem => elem == n);
    }
    list2.add(n)
}
```

Well it's obvious it will be stuck in the `while` loop from method2 for a long time.

Is there a more gentle method to generate numbers so I can avoid waiting?

Comment: Is it me, or does your code only loop 100 times and you are looking for 200 unique numbers and your RandNum only generates from 0 to 100.  This code will not work.  You have some logic errors.  If it did work, I would suggest that you use a hashtable (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.aspx) to store the numbers and the lookup will be fast.

Comment: hmmm, troll?  Your code isnt even valid c#.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like you're trying to generate a random sequence of N numbers.  The approach you're using here is to get a random number and then discard it if it is one you already have.

What you want to do is [Shuffle an Array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) which can be done reasonably efficiently.  Just populate the list with 0, 1, 2, ... in order and then shuffle it.

Pseudocode copied from the above link:

```
To shuffle an array a of n elements (indices 0..n-1):
  for i from n − 1 downto 1 do
       j ← random integer with 0 ≤ j ≤ i
       exchange a[j] and a[i]
```